# Confused by Wigner's friend thought Experiment and Quantum entanglement

Tags: quantum-mechanics

Some questions about Wigner's friend. In [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner%27s_friend),  this system is described as two state spin system $|0\rangle_S$, $|1\rangle_S$ and assume it is in a superposition state $\alpha|0\rangle_S$ +$\beta|1\rangle_S$. From the friend's point of view, when the friend measure the spin in $|0\rangle_S$, $|1\rangle_S$ basis, spin has collapsed into $|0\rangle_S$ or  $|1\rangle_S$ with probability $ \alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$. In Wigner's point of view, he model the combined system of the spin together with his friend (after friend has measured) as  $$ \alpha (|0\rangle_S \otimes |0\rangle_F) + \beta (|1\rangle_S \otimes |1\rangle_F )$$

When Wigner estimate the spin, system will collapsed into $|0\rangle_S\otimes |0\rangle_F$  or $|1\rangle_S\otimes |1\rangle_F$ with probabilty $ \alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$. The spin will be  $|0\rangle_S$ or  $|1\rangle_S$ with probability $ \alpha^2$ and $\beta^2$. (1) Is this right? (2)Is it possible Wigner's friend estimate spin as 0 but  Wigner estimate spin as 1 (different result).

And when I read [Quantum entanglement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_entanglement), consider given two basis vectors ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle \{|0\rangle _{A},|1\rangle _{A}\}}$ of HA and two basis vectors ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle \{|0\rangle _{B},|1\rangle _{B}\}}$ of HB, the following is an entangled state:

$${\displaystyle {\tfrac {1}{\sqrt {2}}}\left(|0\rangle _{A}\otimes |0\rangle _{B}+|1\rangle _{A}\otimes |1\rangle _{B}\right).}$$  Now suppose Alice is an observer for system A, and Bob is an observer for system B. If in the entangled state given above Alice makes a measurement in the ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle \{|0\rangle ,|1\rangle \}}$ eigenbasis of A, there are two possible outcomes, occurring with equal probability.
Alice measures 0, and the state of the system collapses to ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle |0\rangle _{A}|0\rangle _{B}}$ .  Alice measures 1, and the state of the system collapses to ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle |1\rangle _{A}|1\rangle _{B}}$ . When Bob measured the system in the ${\displaystyle \scriptstyle \{|0\rangle ,|1\rangle \}}$ eigenbasis of B after Alice measured. (3) Will Bob always get the same result as Alice (wiki gives this result)? (4) In Bob point of view, what's the state of system after Alice has measured. But when I think this as in Wigner's friend experiment, I think the state should still be $${\displaystyle {\tfrac {1}{\sqrt {2}}}\left(|0\rangle _{A}\otimes |0\rangle _{B}+|1\rangle _{A}\otimes |1\rangle _{B}\right).}$$ And he should get 0 and 1 with equal probability (could be different from Alice's result). Who can explain these correctly. Thanks